# How can I let Hibernate auto-create tables in my database?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2, auto-generate

here is the background:
I am using IntelliJ 2021.3 for Spring development.
My current task is to let an embedded H2 database get initialized with a table schema and test data.

My current application should basically support that behaviour. But what am I missing?

Now I did my research googling through many articles that describe the auto-generation of tables in a database with hibernate mostly in the same way: I have to set *spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto* in the aplication.properties to *create.*

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

I have set up my Entities like this here:

```
package com.learning.classes;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "Course_Id")
    private long courseId;
    @Column(name = "Course_Name")
    private String courseName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Student> student;

    public Course() {
    }

    public Course(long courseId, String courseName) {
        this.courseId = courseId;
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }

    public long getCourseId() {
        return courseId;
    }

    public void setCourseId(long courseId) {
        this.courseId = courseId;
    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

    public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }

    public List<Student> getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public void setStudent(List<Student> student) {
        this.student = student;
    }
}
```

and

```
package com.learning.classes;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "Student_Id")
    private long studentId;
    @Column(name = "First_Name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "Last_Name")
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Course course;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(long studentId, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public long getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(long studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Course getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setCourse(Course course) {
        this.course = course;
    }
}
```

Now I know that there ain't any data to get inserted when starting the app, but at least I should see my tables when I access my H2 via the console.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check [The Spring application property documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html). `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true`

Comment: I added that to my application.properties, but nothing changed. The DB is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out why nothing is working, and to be fully open about it: it was my fault.

I arranged the packages in a way where the Main was not able to read the other packages. The main package was not in the same directory as the others so nothing could happen.

I am writing this so anyone can account on that.

Nevertheless thanks for everyone who has contributed to this topic.

This question is closed.